# All of the static (assets) not found on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I've deployed a Django 1.8 on heroku and none of the static files getting found at all. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong:

```
# settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app123'
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
APPEND_SLASH = False
```

I put all the static files into `myproject/app123/static/(css|images|js)` on localhost. When I run `heroku run python manage.py collectstatic` it doesn't copy anything:

```
$ heroku run python manage.py collectstatic
Running `python manage.py collectstatic` attached to terminal... up, run.7135

You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings:

    /app123/staticfiles

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes

0 static files copied to '/app123/staticfiles', 117 unmodified.
```

Comment: That's telling you the files have been copied. Now, how are you serving from the staticfiles directory? Have you followed [Heroku's instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets), installed Whitenoise, and enabled it in your WSGI file?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, are sure they've been copied? in project/staticfiles I have only "admin" directory.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, they're not found on localhost.